# Borders With Responsive Web Design

Tags: html, css

I'm working on creating a website using responsive web design using information I got from [W3Schools.](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_grid.asp)

The CSS is pretty simple

```
.col-1 {width: 8.33%;}
.col-2 {width: 16.66%;}
.col-3 {width: 25%;}
.col-4 {width: 33.33%;}
.col-5 {width: 41.66%;}
.col-6 {width: 50%;}
.col-7 {width: 58.33%;}
.col-8 {width: 66.66%;}
.col-9 {width: 75%;}
.col-10 {width: 83.33%;}
.col-11 {width: 91.66%;}
.col-12 {width: 100%;}
```

Each column is set up to be a specific width of the screen by a percentage.

What I want is to have 6 "col-2" class div elements side by side on the page which works until I add a border.

The div elements

```
<div class="col-2 greenBorder">Data/info goes here</div>
```

The greenBorder CSS class

```
.greenBorder{
  border-style:solid;
  border-width:2px;
  border-color:#16842e;
}
```

What would I have to do to make these div elements all fit while still having a border?

Comment: `* { box-sizing: border-box;}`

Comment: @Turnip Thanks so much, this was exactly what I needed

Comment: And please, **do not** use W3Schools. See http://w3fools.com.

Comment: @PraveenKumar Thanks, I appreciate it, and I'll be sure to check these out!

Comment: @Fuzzyketchup For the box model thing, see this: **http://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/**

Comment: @PraveenKumar have you actually read the content on w3fools.com recently? Perhaps you should.

Comment: @Turnip Er... What happened? Will do! `:P`

Comment: @Turnip Same contents. Why?

Comment: @PraveenKumar They don't criticise 3wschools anymore. The site has completely changed since it's conception when they heavy criticised w3schools. They actually say _"For many beginners, W3Schools has structured tutorials and playgrounds that offer a decent learning experience."_. So linking to that site without any explanation as to why you think w3schools is bad doesn't really help anyone.

Comment: @Turnip Sure.. Still, w3schools I am reluctant telling it to others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a `border-box` for your `box-sizing`:

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

The reason is, by default, all the `box-model` is of `content-box`, so the `border` makes the `width` go `2px` larger. You can see why here:

[image]
<sub>(source: [binvisions.com](http://www.binvisions.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/css-box-model-border-content_590x328.jpg))</sub>